# Thunderclient api testing get error:Cannot get /api/users data

Tags: web-api-testing, http-method, thunderclient

I got my data for login and register successfully but I am not getting my data after using get request.I don't understand why; can anyone help?

[image: Thunderclient get error image:]

I want that when I use get method, I should get my data which I registered on MongoDB, but its saying cannot get data. I checked everything but it still isn't working. Can you help me why I am getting the error while using get method.

Comment: Could you please share the code where you register the endpoint `/api/user` endpoint in NodeJs? 

And did you verify whether the user `example123` exists in the Mongodb? If yes try to get it manually on the `nodejs` repl. 

You can make use of the vscode debugger as well.

Comment: will do.Actually i am creating it again,will update if things go south. Thanku and sorry for not updating.Also, yes the data was available in mongo.